# How can I create lines using the center of the circles as a reference?

Tags: image-processing

How can I create lines using the center of the circles as a reference?

I created a code, but it generates multiple lines around the circle.

```
coord=PixelValuePositions[imagem,Red];
coord=Sort@coord;
Graphics[{Line[{{coord[[#,1]],coord[[#,2]]}&/@Range[First[Dimensions[coord]]],{coord[[#,1]],coord[[#,2]]}&/@Range[2,First[Dimensions[coord]]]}]}]
```

The image used is at the link below:

[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/znc2ma6se0o3u8q/Imagem%20com%20Pixels.png?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: You mean, how do you draw lines between the circles?

Comment: Exactly what I need.

Comment: Have you looked at `ComponentMeasurements[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`FindClusters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html) to group the pixels

```
coord = FindClusters[ImageValuePositions[imagem, Red], 5];
coord = Table[Mean[coord[[i]]], {i, 1, 5}]
ListPlot[coord]
```

> {{36., 204.}, {347., 184.}, {150., 149.}, {246., 76.}, {71., 39.}}

[image]

```
Show[
 imagem,
 Graphics@Line@Subsets[#, {2}] &@coord]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Strictly speaking instead of `PixelValuePositions` one should use `ImageValuePositions` here because the latter "[assumes the standard image coordinate system.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageValuePositions.html)"

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks. I thought that might be the better option.

Answer (score 8):

As I mentioned, you can use `ComponentMeasurements[]`, at least for this example:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W859.png"];
pts = ComponentMeasurements[SelectComponents[ColorNegate[Binarize[img]],
                                             Small], "Centroid"];

HighlightImage[img, GraphicsComplex[Range[5] /. pts, {Blue, Line[Subsets[Range[5], {2}]]}]]
```

[image: lines on the image]

Comment: What version and OS are you on?

Comment: It shouldn't have problems, then. Try the code in a fresh session.

Comment: Try applying `Normal[]` to the `GraphicsComplex[]` object before passing it to `HighlightImage[]`.

Comment: Wait... can you give the precise version that you have? `ComponentMeasurements[]` was introduced in 10.3, you see.

Comment: After running the first two lines in a fresh session, what does the output of `pts` look like?

Comment: Sorry to be insisting on getting a response, but do it because you already helped me a lot and I see that you have a lot of experience with this software.

Comment: The `Format type of new output cells` is `TraditionalForm`, this has an influence?

Comment: That's not what I was asking for. Restart *Mathematica*, and run the two lines before the one with `HighlightImage[]`. What does `pts` look like?

Comment: `{1->{36.,204.},2->{347.,184.},3->{150.,149.},4->{246.,76.},5->{71.,39.}}`

Comment: OK. Now, try running `HighlightImage[img, Flatten @ Normal @ GraphicsComplex[Range[5] /. pts, {Blue, Line[Subsets[Range[5], {2}]]}]]`